# Special (Meta) Characters while using Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

In a response : there is a string like this.

**,"Software":"**abcde**",**

and i want to select **abcde**

i write the regular Expression as **,"Software":"([^"]+)",**

then i used this variable in a GET request and a POST request.

in GET request it works but in POST request doesnt.

when i look at the post request i see some **%** characters. but they are not included in **abcde** string.
in **abcde** string some special characters like **+** and **/** may be present. and they will not transmitted properly to the request.
Why do yo think so? And are there any solution for this?

Comment: Could you please share the screenshot for GET and POST request including the REGEX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check the variable value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script), if the variable contains these "special" characters and they should not be there - amend your regular expression accordingly
2. If your response is in JSON format it worth considering switching to [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor,)

With regards to these `%` and `/`, can it be connected with [URL Encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)?

[image]